# How create TS interface with dynamic key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic, interface

`keyArray = [key1, key2, key3,...] //this is dynamic value array.`

I want to create TS interface like below one using keyArray.

```
interface = {
  key1 : string;
  key2 : string;
  key3 : string;
  ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean - types only exist at compile time, they're erased by run time (because JavaScript isn't typed).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do this precisely because it depends on how your variables `key1` etc. are typed.

We can get the type of the values of `keyArray` with `(typeof keyArray)[number]` and we can create a type with those types as keys and `string` as the value:

```
type FromKeys = Record<(typeof keyArray)[number], string>
```

But the key type is is *type* of `key1`, etc. -- not the *value*.  If the type of `key1` is a string literal this will be exactly what you want.  But if the type of `key1` is just `string` then your `FromKeys` type will allow any `string` property and won't be particularly useful.

```
type FromKeys<T extends readonly PropertyKey[]> = Record<T[number], string>

declare function makeObject<T extends readonly PropertyKey[]>(keyArray: T): FromKeys<T>;

const obj1 = makeObject(["a", "b", "c"]); // Record<string, string>
const obj2 = makeObject(["a", "b", "c"] as const); // Record<"a" | "b" | "c", string>
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/GmZpaw)